# How to join Prompt with SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, prompt

I am totally new to Javascript. I started my course just this week. I even don't know if we post HTML code here or not.
I have a question about delaying prompt with `if` statment. 
I tried a lot of things shown here about alerts and confirmation, but they are not applied on prompt. 
Here is my code (which is very primitive), so please show me how to delay prompt, with an `if` statment .

What I want to do is: I want the user to read the choices 1st for 10 seconds before the Prompt shows up, then the prompt gives you a choice. Depending on the choice, the results changes.

```
<meta chartset = "utf-8">
<h1> Car </h1>
In 10 seconds, you can choose your destination BY NUMBER
<br>
Higiénopolis   : 1
<br>
Santa Cécilia  : 2
<br>
Vila Madalena  : 3
<br>

<script>

var hi = 1
var sc = 2
var vm = 3
var dest=prompt("Choose your destination :");

if(dest==1){
    document.write("<br>Your position is Caelum.")
    document.write("<br>Your destination is Higiénopolis.")
    document.write("<br> A distancia é : 7 km")
    document.write("<br> O tempo para chegar é : 28 min")
}
if(dest==2){
    document.write("<br>Your position is Caelum.")
    document.write("<br>Your destination is Santa Cécilia.")
    document.write("<br> A distancia é : 9,4 km")
    document.write("<br> O tempo para chegar é : 31 min")
}
if(dest==3){
    document.write("<br>Your position is Caelum.")
    document.write("<br>Your destination is Vila Madalena.")
    document.write("<br> A distancia é : 10 km")
    document.write("<br> O tempo para chegar é : 35")
}
</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { /* your code here */ }, 10000)`. Note that `document.write()` is not generally a good idea, and definitely isn't a good idea after the page has already finished loading (which would be the case if you use a ten second timeout).

Comment: You said that "document.write() is not generally a good idea"
Is there another alternative?
Till now I just learned about "document.write()" that shows the content in the next page after a prompt. And "exibe()" that shows the content in the same page. I hope I explained well....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout

```
var hi = 1
var sc = 2
var vm = 3
var dest = '';

setTimeout(function() {
  dest = prompt("Choose your destination :");
  if (dest == 1) {
    document.write("<br>Your position is Caelum.")
    document.write("<br>Your destination is Higiénopolis.")
    document.write("<br> A distancia é : 7 km")
    document.write("<br> O tempo para chegar é : 28 min")
  }
  if (dest == 2) {
    document.write("<br>Your position is Caelum.")
    document.write("<br>Your destination is Santa Cécilia.")
    document.write("<br> A distancia é : 9,4 km")
    document.write("<br> O tempo para chegar é : 31 min")
  }
  if (dest == 3) {
    document.write("<br>Your position is Caelum.")
    document.write("<br>Your destination is Vila Madalena.")
    document.write("<br> A distancia é : 10 km")
    document.write("<br> O tempo para chegar é : 35")
  }

}, 2000)
```

Note : The conditional statements are also inside setTimeout, because, it is an asynchronous function.

If you want to keep it outside, put it in a different function and call that function

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/w53m19v9/)

Comment: Thank you "nnnnnn"
It worked just fine and smooth. 
As they say here in Brasil, Beleza.